# Populate iTextSharp pdf with database values

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

I have this code below and trying to populate my pdf with values from the database.

```
 PdfPCell points = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("and is therefore entitled to ", arialCertify));
points.Colspan = 2;
points.Border = 0;
points.PaddingTop = 40f;
points.HorizontalAlignment = 1;//0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
// code below needs attention
var cID = "ALFKI";
var xw = Customers.First(p => p.CustomerID ==cID);
table.AddCell(xw.CompanyName.ToString());
```

I can not figure out where I am going wrong. When I remove the code under 'code below needs attention' it works but I need the database values.

I am using webmatrix with ItextSharp. If to answer you need further code please let me know.

Comment: What *does* go wrong? Any error messages?

Comment: no error message. Webmatrix doent show error on this one. Appreciate your question.

Comment: You create a PdfPCell points and you don't use it anywhere. We have no idea what the Customers class or object is about. We have no idea whatsover to which table you're adding a cell with the company name. Your question is seriously broken and therefore I've voted to close it.

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfPCell cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(xw.CompanyName.ToString()));
cell.setColspan(numColumns);
table.addCell(cell);
document.add(table);
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan. Still not working. Replaced numColumns with 2 and 3.Could it that my query is wrong?

Comment: You need the setColspan argument set to the number of columns in your table or add more blank cells to your table to match the number of columns in your table. You can hardcode a value in the Phrase constructor to see if it is iText or your code that is causing the issue. If you still are having problems with iText show all your code and I'll look at it.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a question. Nobody will be able to tell you what is wrong with your query because you're not telling us anything about your query. Are you having a database problem? Are you having an iTextSharp problem? What is your question about? Nobody but you can tell.

Comment: Only issue I can think of off hand where his code would be a problem is if his Linq statement is throwing an exception because the value doesn't exist. Might want to use FirstOrDefault() and check for null.

Comment: @Dylan I am checking your suggestions. At the meantime, I have pasetd the all the code on http://pastebin.com/BpVtSb0j . Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Bruno-Lowagie I am not having a database problem. Its likely my query syntax. What I am asking is how do I take the value from the query and have it on a cell.

Comment: @SitheloNgwenya If your code works with a hard coded value instead of with a value retrieved from the query, then it's not an iTextSharp problem. If it doesn't work with a hard coded value, you've made your question needlessly complex by talking about the database query. Take one out of two out of the equation: either don't talk about iTextSharp or don't talk about the query.